# Looping over an array and accessing properties of the currently looped-over object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

Hey guys i'm working on an assignment and i am having difficulty but not sure what it is I am missing. it keeps throwing an error on Step 4

I am not really sure how to structure the code to satisfy the requirements for Step 4

and and all help is appreciated here.

Assignment Instructions
In this exercise, you will work with some data provided as an array of objects, listing information about dishes available in the Little Lemon restaurant.

Step 1: In the function getPrices(), give it the parameter of taxBoolean.

Step 2: Inside the getPrices() function, code a for loop that will loop over all the objects inside the dishData array.

Step 3: Inside the for loop, declare a finalPrice variable, without assigning it a value.

Step 4: Still inside the for loop, add an if condition, checking that the taxBoolean is set to true. Inside the if block, multiply the following: * the price of the currently looped-over object from the dishData array, and * the tax value. Assign the multiplied value to the finalPrice variable.

Step 5: Right after the if condition, add an else if, checking if the value of taxBoolean is false. Inside this condition's block, assign the currently looped-over dish price property in the dishData array to the finalPrice variable.

Step 6: Code the else case, and inside of it, add two lines of code:

A console log of the string:

"You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!"

return (to "jump out" of the further function execution)

Step 7: After all the conditional's statements, but still inside the for loop, code another console log with four arguments:

The string "Dish: "

The value of currently looped-over dish object's name property

The string "Price: $"

The value of the finalPrice variable

Step 8: You're finshed with the getPrices() function, and now you're ready to code another function. Give the getDiscount() function, two parameters: the taxBoolean and the guests parameter.

Step 9: Inside the getDiscount() function, on the very first line of its body, invoke the getPrices() function, passing it the taxBoolean as an argument.

Step 10: On another line, you need to implement your defensive coding skills, and check that the type of the guests parameter is 'number' and that the value of the guests variable is greater than zero and less than 30. If all these conditions return true, code the body of the conditional as described in the next step. If they don't all return true, code the body of the else conditional as instructed in step 12.

Step 11: Inside the if statment, declare a new variable, named discount, and set it to 0. On the next line, add another if...else if: in the first if, you'll check that the value of the guests variable is less than 5. If that's the case, reassign the value of the discount variable to 5;

Inside the else if condition, check that the value of the guests variable is greater than or equal to 5 - if that's the case, reassign the discount variable to 10.
Console log the following after closing your else-if statement: 'Discount is: $' + discount);
Step 12: In the else condition, console log the following string: 'The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30'. Since you've finished declaring both the getPrices() and the getDiscount() functions, you can now invoke the getDiscount() function several times, with various combinations of arguments, to check the behavior.

Here are two examples:

getDiscount(true, 2)
getDiscount(false, 10)
What happens when you don't pass-in any arguments?

What happens when you pass values that are not expected?

```
// Given variables
const dishData = [
    {
        name: "Italian pasta",
        price: 9.55
    },
    {
        name: "Rice with veggies",
        price: 8.65
    },
    {
        name: "Chicken with potatoes",
        price: 15.55
    },
    {
        name: "Vegetarian Pizza",
        price: 6.45
    },
]
const tax = 1.20;

// Implement getPrices()

function getPrices(taxBoolean) {   //step1
    let finalPrice = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++) {   // step 2
         let finalPrice = 0                                           // step 3
        if (taxBoolean == true) {                  // step 4
            let name = dishData[i]['name'];
            let price = dishData[i]['price'];  // Step 4
            //console.log('Prices with 20% tax:');
            console.log(`Dish: ${name}, Price (incl. tax): $${+price * tax}`);
                  
        } else if (taxBoolean == false) {            //step 5
            let name = dishData[i]['name'];
            let price = dishData[i]['price'];
            console.log('Prices without tax:'); {
                console.log(`Dish: ${name}, Price (incl. tax): $${+price}`);
            }
        } else {                                        //step 6
            console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!")
            return;
        }
    }
}
console.log(getPrices(true));
console.log(getPrices(false));

  
// Implement getDiscount()

    function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {   //Step 8
        getPrices(taxBoolean);                   //Step 9
        try {                                    //Step 10
            if (typeof (guests) != 'number' && (guests) < 0 && (guests) > 30) {  //Step 11
                var discount = 0;
                if (typeof (guests) < 5) {
                    discount = 5;
                }
                else if (typeof (guests) >= 5) {
                    discount = 10;
                    console.log('Discount is: $' + discount);
                }
                else {                                                          //step 12
                    console.log('the second argument must be a number between 0 and 30')
                }
            }
        } catch (err) { // Code throws error
            alert('catch', err);
        }
    }


//Call getDiscount();
getDiscount(true, 2);
getDiscount(false, 10)
```

Comment: **O**bject.values but I am not sure what you are actually trying to do here with looping over an array and using an Object values on an array??

Comment: trying to multiply the values in price * tax      Step 4 Inside the if block, multiply the following: * the price of the currently looped-over object from the dishData array, and * the tax value. Assign the multiplied value to the finalPrice variable.

Comment: That does not work. You would need to loop over the array. There is no code that will take an array and update all the indexes. Maybe you meant `dishData[i]` to get the current index

Comment: you will work data provided as an array of objects, listing information about dishes in the Little Lemon restaurant.
You will need to write a function declaration which will be able to do two things:
If the function is called with the argument true, it will output the names of the dishes and calculate their final price (including 20% tax)

If the function is called with the argument false, it will output the names of the dishes and give their prices without the additional tax
The expected outcome is that all the dishes' names and prices will be shown in the console output.

Comment: this what the assignment outcome is looking for just not sure how to get it.

Comment: You are iterating over keys, must be something like
`
var var finalPrice = 0;
 for (let [k, v] in Object.entries(dishData))
{ 
finalPrice += v * tax);
}
`

Comment: The text below shows the output that your code should produce:

Prices with 20% tax:
Dish: Italian pasta Price (incl.tax): $ 11.46
Dish: Rice with veggies Price (incl.tax): $ 10.38
Dish: Chicken with potatoes Price (incl.tax): $ 18.66
Dish: Vegetarian Pizza Price (incl.tax): $ 7.74

Prices without tax:
Dish: Italian pasta Price (incl.tax): $ 9.55
Dish: Rice with veggies Price (incl.tax): $ 8.65
Dish: Chicken with potatoes Price (incl.tax): $ 15.55
Dish: Vegetarian Pizza Price (incl.tax): $ 6.45

Comment: ok i changed that line of code Mesi, but now i'm getting : [Running] node "/home/coder/project/learn/finalProject.js"
NaN

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.079 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Your console for **getPrices()** `console.log`(`Dish: ${name} Price: $${finalPrice}`) can appear after the `ifelse`.

```js
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++) {
    let finalPrice = "";
    let name = dishData[i].name;
    let price = dishData[i].price;

    if (taxBoolean === true) {
      finalPrice = price * tax;
    } else if (taxBoolean === false) {
      finalPrice = price;
    } else {
      console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!");
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Dish: ${name} Price: $${finalPrice}`);
  }
}
// Implement getDiscount()
function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {
  getPrices(taxBoolean);

  try {
    if (typeof guests === "number" && guests > 0 && guests < 30) {
      let discount = 0;

      if (guests < 5) {
        discount = 5;
      } else if (guests >= 5) {
        discount = 10;
      }
      console.log("Discount is: $" + discount);
    } else {
      console.log("The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30");
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}

// Call getDiscount()
getDiscount(true, 2);
getDiscount(false, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Given variables
const dishData = [
    {
        name: "Italian pasta",
        price: 9.55
    },
    {
        name: "Rice with veggies",
        price: 8.65
    },
    {
        name: "Chicken with potatoes",
        price: 15.55
    },
    {
        name: "Vegetarian Pizza",
        price: 6.45
    },
]
const tax = 1.20;

function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
  for (let dish of dishData) {
    let finalPrice;

    if (taxBoolean) {
      finalPrice = dish.price * tax;
    } else if (!taxBoolean) {
      finalPrice = dish.price;
    } else {
      console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!");
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Dish: ${dish.name} Price: $${finalPrice}`);
  }
}

function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {
  getPrices(taxBoolean);

  if (typeof guests === 'number' && guests > 0 && guests < 30) {
    let discount = 0;

    if (guests < 5) {
      discount = 5;
    } else
 
if (guests >= 5) {
      discount = 10;
    }

    console.log(`Discount is: $${discount}`);
  } else {
    console.log('The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30');
  }
}

getDiscount(true, 2); 
getDiscount(false, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this when taxed:

```js
var finalPrice = 0;
dishData.forEach((dish)=>{
  finalPrice+=dish.price*tax;
})
```

Just remove the multiplication by tax when not being taxed, or if you want to simplify the code further try a one line if for `taxBoolean`:

```js
var finalPrice = 0;
dishData.forEach((dish)=>{
  finalPrice+=dish.price * (taxBoolean ? tax : 1);
})
```

This makes it so you don't check for `taxBoolean` when getting the final price. Regarding the if statements in `GetPrices` you only need an if for `true` and an else for `false`, unless its some null or undefined type variable.

If for some reason you want to return the array of taxed prices instead of the total taxed price, use the `map` function for the `dishData` array.

```js
var finalPrice = dishData.map((dish)=>dish.price*(taxBoolean ? tax : 1));
```

`dishData` is an array of objects not an object itself, so you need to iterate over it and add the `price` property multiplied with `tax`. Consider renaming `dishData` to `dishes` or something plural to show that its an array.

ALSO do not re-declare `finalPrice` either remove the `var finalPrice = ""` line or change it to `var finalPrice=0;` and remove the other `var finalPrice = 0;` in the if statements.

Comment: i made those changes but it is adding all the prices of the dishes together with tax and returning 48.24 as the result.

Comment: @MattP Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The text below shows the output that your code should produce:
```
Prices with 20% tax:
Dish: Italian pasta Price (incl.tax): $ 11.46
Dish: Rice with veggies Price (incl.tax): $ 10.38
Dish: Chicken with potatoes Price (incl.tax): $ 18.66
Dish: Vegetarian Pizza Price (incl.tax): $ 7.74

Prices without tax:
Dish: Italian pasta Price (incl.tax): $ 9.55
Dish: Rice with veggies Price (incl.tax): $ 8.65
Dish: Chicken with potatoes Price (incl.tax): $ 15.55
Dish: Vegetarian Pizza Price (incl.tax): $ 6.45   ```

Comment: it is supposed to list the dish with each price either taxed or not depending on the true / false condition

Comment: Oh, so a seperate tax for each dish?, but then a single variable won't really work.

Comment: yeah i need to list each dish with its corresponding price adjusted or not for tax

Comment: @MattP in that case use a seperate array `isTaxedArr` or better add a isTaxed boolean in your dishes, like `{name: "Italian Pasta", price: 9.55, isTaxed: true}` then just use that `isTaxed` via `dish.isTaxed`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with a little help from a friend.

```
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {   //step1
   for (var i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++) {   // step 2
         let finalPrice = 0                                           // step 3
        if (taxBoolean == true) {                  // step 4
            let name = dishData[i]['name'];
            let price = dishData[i]['price'];  // Step 4
            finalPrice = price * tax
            console.log(`Dish: ${name}` + " " + `Price: $${finalPrice}`)      
        } else if (taxBoolean == false) {            //step 5
            let name = dishData[i]['name'];
            let price = dishData[i]['price'];
            //console.log('Prices without tax:');
            finalPrice = price
            console.log(`Dish: ${name}` + " " + `Price: $${finalPrice}`)
        } else {                                        //step 6
            console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!")
            return;
        }
    }
}
console.log(getPrices(true));
console.log(getPrices(false));


  
// Implement getDiscount()

    function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {   //Step 8
        getPrices(taxBoolean);                   //Step 9
        try {                                    //Step 10
            if (typeof(guests) == 'number' && guests > 0 && guests < 30) {  //Step 11
                let discount = 0;
                    if (guests < 5) {
                        discount = 5;
                        console.log('Discount is: $' + discount);
                        
                    } else if (guests >= 5) {
                        discount = 10;
                        console.log('Discount is: $' + discount);
                    }
            } else {                                                          //step 12
                console.log('the second argument must be a number between 0 and 30');
            }
        } catch (err) { // Code throws error
            console.log('catch', err);
        }
    }
//Call getDiscount();

console.log(getDiscount(true, 2));
console.log(getDiscount(false, 10));
```